# How to use color bar in polar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am trying to use color bar in polar plot. I didn't get. Here is my code for simple polar plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

y2 = [96.31883883883884, 105.53807807807806, 96.4374174174175, 94.50975975975975, 82.67206206206207, 125.8472472472473, 126.62304304304303, 124.98103103103091, 117.13329329329326, 109.36357357357365, 107.02209209209208, 117.19069069069054, 96.31883883883884]
y3 = [242.29120120120174, 227.6075375375375, 220.69459459459455, 222.21662324649296, 225.59189189189183, 218.9322422422421, 219.08093093093117, 226.80649649649635, 229.3265965965969, 201.60476476476458, 196.92468468468442, 190.94575575575595, 242.29120120120174]
y4 = [31.625100401606428, 36.0695295295295, 35.989519038076125, 38.314428857715434, 40.236536536536505, 67.78894894894894, 68.63077077077074, 64.99336336336333, 63.45824824824829, 63.41446446446452, 61.0178978978978, 63.99864864864866, 31.625100401606428]

z = np.arange(0, 13)
theta1 = (2*np.pi/12)*z
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.42, 0.36, 0.18, 0.30], polar=True, axisbg='white')
ax1.plot(theta1, y2, color='black', lw=2)       
ax1.plot(theta1, y3, color='blue', lw=2)        
ax1.plot(theta1, y4, color='green', lw=2)

ax1.set_rmax(500)

ax1.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax1.set_xticklabels(['N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW'], color='red')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Colorbars are mainly useful when working with colormaps. Here you do not have a colormap. Can you go more in detail about what the colorbar is supposed to show?

Comment: The shown plot would be created via `pcolormesh`. So before thinking about colorbars, try to get the polar plot straight. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513312/polar-heatmaps-in-python

Comment: I think, according to your link, rad = y2, azm = theta1. I didn't understand z! This is for one list but I have 3 different  values (y2, y3, y4) inside the one polar plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea would be to create a `pcolormesh` plot of the data. To this end one will need to define coordinate arrays for theta and r first.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y2 = [96.31883883883884, 105.53807807807806, 96.4374174174175, 94.50975975975975, 82.67206206206207, 125.8472472472473, 126.62304304304303, 124.98103103103091, 117.13329329329326, 109.36357357357365, 107.02209209209208, 117.19069069069054, 96.31883883883884]
y3 = [242.29120120120174, 227.6075375375375, 220.69459459459455, 222.21662324649296, 225.59189189189183, 218.9322422422421, 219.08093093093117, 226.80649649649635, 229.3265965965969, 201.60476476476458, 196.92468468468442, 190.94575575575595, 242.29120120120174]
y4 = [31.625100401606428, 36.0695295295295, 35.989519038076125, 38.314428857715434, 40.236536536536505, 67.78894894894894, 68.63077077077074, 64.99336336336333, 63.45824824824829, 63.41446446446452, 61.0178978978978, 63.99864864864866, 31.625100401606428]

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, len(y2))
r = [1,2,3,4]

z = [y2,y3,y4]

fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

pc = ax.pcolormesh(theta, r, z)

fig.colorbar(pc)

ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_xticklabels(['N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW'], color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! How to divide one bin in to two bins lets say 0-30 in to 0-15 and 15-30?

Comment: You need one more value for each value in the lists (except the last one), and twice as many theta values.

Comment: Yes, I have one more value at  the list of y2 let's say 70.23657983464534 at 345° .But rest of the values are same. I only  want to split 330 to 360 single bin in to 330 to 345 and 345 to 360.

Comment: I also have another question! I have data at exactly 0°, 30°, 60° and so on. According to your plot bin is starting from 0°  to 30°, and so on . How to start bin from let's say 345° to 15, 15 to 45 and so on. I want to face the center of each bin towards 0°, 30°, and so on.