# Is there a way to plot a polar heatmap incrementally?

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I am trying to have a polar heatmap appear incrementally. I want the plot to grow by adding a deltasector to the existing plot. The same maximal radius is always used.

For now I replot the old data as well, but that is only because I do not know how to add to the existing plot.

How do I add z values for the new angle to an existing heatmap?

The accepted answer here gives shows how to plot a polar heatmap:
[Polar heatmaps in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513312/polar-heatmaps-in-python)

In the code below the z values are calculated as a function of the r and th. My situation is however that I read the values from a file instead.
How would I add them to the heatmap?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import time

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

angle = 0
rad = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)

d_angle = np.pi/100

while angle < np.pi:
    azm = np.linspace(0, angle, 100)
    r, th = np.meshgrid(rad, azm)
    z = r/5

    plt.subplot(projection="polar")

    plt.pcolormesh(th, r, z)

    plt.plot(azm, r, color='k', ls='none') 
    plt.grid()
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
    plt.clf()
    angle += d_angle
```

I do not know where to start. Any pointers to docs? Or other advices?

Comment: From the answer below you see that people have problems understanding the question. I'd recommend you spend more words on what you are trying to achieve and also describe what your current code does and why that is not what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the data from a `plot` by looking into `ax.lines`. Add a "gid" to your curve like so `plt.plot(azm, r, color='k', ls='none', gid="a custom name")` then we have a little work to do:

```
def append_data_to_curve(ax, gid):
    for line in ax.lines: # Check every curve.
        if line.get_gid() == "a custom name": # If the one you seek is found:
            X = line.get_xdata() # Get its X and Y data.
            Y = line.get_ydata()
            X.append(x) # Add the new point (x,y) you want.
            Y.append(y)
            line.set_xdata(X) # Put back the modified list as curve data.
            line.set_ydata(Y)
```

You can call this function for every iteration of a loop and add a single new point by giving it its (x,y) coordinates.