# Plotting polar heatmap from 3 column file with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, heatmap, polar-coordinates

I am currently working my way through matplotlib, trying to get away from gnuplot. 
My current idea is to create a heatmap in polar coordinates from a file whichs looks like this

```
rad1 theta1 value
rad1 theta2 value
rad1 theta3 value
... ... ...
rad2 theta1 value
rad2 theta2 value
rad2 theta3 value
...
```

This is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
a=np.loadtxt("radtheta.txt")


#read in data file
r=a[:,0]
t=a[:,1]*360#convert to degrees
z=a[:,2]


A, B = np.meshgrid(r, t)

plt.subplot(projection="polar")
plt.pcolormesh(A,B, z)
plt.show()
```

However, I always end up with this error:

```
numRows, numCols = C.shape
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I understand it has something to do with the shape of my data?
Can anybody help me out on this?
Thanks!

Comment: Where do you define `C`?

Comment: I think that is some internal line from one of the modules. Complete error code:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5395, in pcolormesh
    X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args, allmatch=allmatch)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 4995, in _pcolorargs
    numRows, numCols = C.shape
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: `pcolormap` expects rectangular coordinates and a 2-dimensional third parameter. Have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513312/polar-heatmaps-in-python)?

Comment: Yes, I know that question. That gave me the idea of using meshgrid and projection=polar.
However, my z values are not a function of the radius. Is there another plotting option or can I transform my 1d z values into a suitable array somehow?